# Have to use skip() or read() dependin on how application is launched

Tags: java, inputstream, skip

I have a file with some data in it. Each data chunk has an indexed start position so I can quickly access it. Depending on how the program is launched (Via IDE or opening the .jar file), doing `input.read()` gives a difference result.

This is the code block I use:

NB: It appears it only happens to that one file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    //The index is at position 137.
    int indexPos = (Character.SIZE / 8) * 137;

    InputStream stream = InputStream stream = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/data/data.dat");

    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Use skip?");
    if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
        //Skips bytes to get to index position.
        stream.skip(indexPos);
    }
    else
    {
        //Reads bytes to get to index position.
        stream.read(new byte[indexPos]);
    }

    byte[] contentStart = new byte[2];
    stream.read(contentStart);

    //The content itself start at this position.
    int contentStartPos = ByteBuffer.wrap(contentStart).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asCharBuffer().get();

    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Use skip?");

    if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
        //Skips bytes to get to the correct position.
        stream.skip(contentStartPos - indexPos - 2);
    }
    else
    {
        //Reads bytes to get to the correct position.
        stream.read(new byte[contentStartPos - indexPos - 2]);
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Should be 0 and is: "+stream.read());
}
```

Here is the values of the byte being read at the end:

```
//The correct value needed is 0.
In IDE & yes yes: 108
In IDE & no no: 0
In IDE & yes no: 0
In IDE & no yes: 112
Via JAR & yes yes: 0
Via JAR & no no: 4
Via JAR and yes no: 4
Via JAR and no yes: 0
```

As you can see, the first skip/read doesn't matter what it is in order to get the correct value. Only the second one.

I would love for someone to explain to me why this would happen.

Edit: Here are the values being skipped the 2nd time:

```
//The correct value is 8235.
In IDE using skip: 8190
In IDE using read: 8235
Via JAR using skip: 8235
Via JAR using read: 8192
```

Comment: do I understand correctly? The result should be 0 in all combinations

Comment: @blackbird014 Yes. I just added the amount of bytes being read/skipped. I understand that it can wary, but for a local file I don't see how it can not read the requested bytes. And why it switches depending on how the application is opened.

Comment: can u try `while ((len = in.read(indexPos)) != -1);`  for the read() and tell me what happens (If now the result is consistent?). About skip(): skips over and discards n bytes of data from this input stream. The skip method may, for a variety of reasons, end up skipping over some smaller number of bytes, possibly 0. This may result from any of a number of conditions; reaching end of file before n bytes have been skipped is only one possibility. The actual number of bytes skipped is returned. Plz print also the byte skipped and we try to understand the behavior there.

Answer (score 0):

If one reads the Javadoc for the InputStream.skip() method:

> Skips over and discards n bytes of data from this input stream. The skip method may, for a variety of reasons, end up skipping over some smaller number of bytes, possibly 0. This may result from any of a number of conditions; reaching end of file before n bytes have been skipped is only one possibility. The actual number of bytes skipped is returned.

You'll need to put your skip in a loop that actually skips the bytes correctly. This is a common mistake people make, I know I have in the past. As you can see the method actually returns a long which you can use to keep track of the actual bytes skipped.

I hope this helps.